# extracting libraries to separate file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to extract libraries in a separate vendor.js file.

In webpack.config.js (webpack 4), I do this :

```
entry: {
    app: './resources/assets/js/app.js',
    vendor: ['vue', 'axios']
},

output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: './public'
}
```

In the end, I have my app.js and vendor.js

The vendor.js file includes both vue and axios.

In my html file, at the end, I add the 2 scripts :

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
```

But app.js does not know about Vue or axios.
I get "ReferenceError: Vue is not define".

Same if putting vendor.js before app.js in the html file.

Should I add a line in my "app.js" entry point, so that I import vue and axios in some way, without adding the libraries in the "app.js" output ?

Comment: Did you try moving the vendor script above the app script so it's loaded first?

Comment: Yes, same problem. Maybe I need to add something at the top of "app.js" entry file ?

Comment: Are you doing an `import` or `require`? You'll still need those if you're just currently trying to access `Vue` as a global.

Comment: In app.js entry, if I do `import Vue from 'vue'`, it will add vue in my app.js bundle.  It will not use my "vendor.js" file.

Comment: It shouldn't with that webpack config; are you seeing it do that?

Comment: Yes. Same with `require('vue')`.  It des not require from my "vendor.js" file. It is adding the full "vue" inside my "app.js" bundled file.

Comment: Are you loading `CommonsChunkPlugin`? Sounds like you're wanting to use this pattern: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#explicit-vendor-chunk

Comment: I'll try that. But what's the reason why my setup is not working ?   Why "Vue" is not accessible ?

Comment: It normally isn't, unless you're building UMD packages maybe (not sure if that's the default). Normally, you just do the `require` or `import` and webpack converts those imports into properly loading it from the vendor file.

Comment: Where do I require/import ?  In my app.js ?   As I said, this will import the full library. I want to use the libraries that was bundled into vendor.js.

Comment: It doesn't import the full library if you have that plugin.

Comment: So you mean I still to have use `import Vue from 'vue'`, and with the library, it will look inside "vendor.js" ?  Now the library is called "splitChunks". Using default settings, it still imports the library into app.js.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for Webpack 4, using "splitChunks" or not.

Comment: Yes, you still import normally. This sample shows how to set up specific packages that you want in that separate chunk: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#split-chunks-example-3 (just tweak that `test` regexp)

Comment: Wow, this is working ! And I don't need the vendor entry point. Thank you ! You can post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Webpack 4 way of splitting out a "vendor" chunk is via the [`SplitChunksPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/). You can configure this plugin through the `optimization.splitChunks` config path:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](vue|axios)[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Perhaps counter-intuitively, the way to reference these modules after this configuration remains the same; how `vue` and `axios` are loaded is decided by the webpack config; you don't have to change any code that used to import these modules. `require('vue')` or `import axios from 'axios'` will cause these modules to be referenced from your `vendor.js` file.

Finally, re-order your script tags so that `app.js` doesn't try to load things from `vendor.js` before `vendor.js` is loaded.

```
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```